# Is there a link on the meta site back to the parent site?

Tags: feature-request, links, meta

This is probably a dumb question, and I just am not seeing it, but is there a link somewhere convenient on the meta site to go back to the parent site?

If it's there, I am totally missing it.

If it's not there, could we add one?  I think it would be useful.

Comment: Similarly, it would be nice to have a quick link to meta from the parent site...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are links both ways, in the bar at the very top of the screen.  To the right of your username and reputation number will be a few links.  On the parent site you'll see a link called "meta" and on the meta site you'll see a link called "parent" - they do what you're asking for.

Comment: Well, duh, there it is!  Thanks, can't believe I couldn't see it.

Comment: @seanmc: likewise!  I'd never noticed it before either.